# Pandas DataFrames to Graph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Given two DataFrames, one for Nodes and another for Edges. How can I get those into a networkx graph including the attribute columns I have?

Example:

df_nodes

|  | ID | Label | Attribute_W | Attribute_X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Japan | Asia | 81 |
| 1 | 1 | Mexico | America | 52 |
| 2 | 2 | Ireland | Europe | 353 |

df_Edges

|  | Target | Source | Attribute_Y | Attribute_Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 15 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 20 | 3 |

I tried with **G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist** but it returns an attribute error. And I'm not sure of how to add the attributes in the construction of the graph.

I'm looking to output a graphml file **nx.write_graphml(G, "My_File.graphml")**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too do not see any way how to include node attributes via from_pandas_edgelist. However, you can achieve what you want just using nx.add_edges_from and nx.add_nodes_from in a few lines of code.

```
G = nx.Graph()

node_label_attr = "Label"
for index,row in df_nodes.iterrows():
    as_dict = row.to_dict()
    label = as_dict[node_label_attr]
    del as_dict[node_label_attr]
    G.add_nodes_from([(label, as_dict)])

for index,row in df_Edges.iterrows():
    as_dict = row.to_dict()
    source = as_dict["Source"]
    target = as_dict["Target"]
    del as_dict["Source"]
    del as_dict["Target"]
    G.add_edges_from([(source,target,as_dict)])
```

You iterate through the rows of the dataframe and convert them to dictionaries which are understood by nx.add_nodes_from and nx.add_edges_from.